# Working with android contact aggregation

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I have been trying to understand how the 'Contacts Framework' in android works.

My use case is similar to WhatsApp`s friends list :

1. If new contact is added, the sync adapter should be invoked.
2. if the 'name' of an existing contact is changed, the changes should appear in my list too.

Its the **2nd** point I need help with.

Now, reading all the docs, I think this is how it should work :

- You register an account to the  `Account Manager` with `my_account_type`.
- You add a `RawContact` with `my_account_name` and `my_account_type`.
- For the above RawContact's `_id`, add `ContactsContract.Data` with a `MIME` value as `Phone.CONTETN_TYPE_ITEM` and add the `phone number` to that data.
- For the same RawContact's `_id`, add `ContactsCtonract.Data` with a `MIME' value as`my_custom_mime_type` and add app specific data to it.

Now, the 'Contact aggregtor' aggregates the contacts based on `MIME`=`Phone.CONTENT_TYPE_ITEM` and its value and thus join thie RawContact with all other contacts having same value of `Phone.CONTENT_TYPE_ITEM`.

**So question number 1 : Is that what actually happens ?**

Now, if the above is true, while fetching the data in app's list, one can use `ContentProvider#query()` and look for `my_custom_mime_type`, and get `StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME` to get the display name. The framework has this `StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME` because it has aggregated the contact, that `MyApp` added, to all other similar contacts.

**Quetion number 2 : It not working for me this way. instead I am getting the `phone number` as the `DIPLAY_NAME`**

I tried to look into WhatsApp's RawContact :

```
RawContact : WhatsApp - com.whatsapp - 87211 - 87210 - null
 Raw : WhatsApp count : 5
    >> DISPLAY_NAME for this : display_name_person
    >> vnd.android.cursor.item/name > display_name_person - 0 -  end_name - null - null - null - null - null - null
    >> vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.profile > xxxxxxxxxxxx@s.whatsapp.net - 0 -  Message +91 xxxxx xxxxx - null - null - null - null - null - null
    >> vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call > xxxxxxxxxxxx@s.whatsapp.net - 0 -  Voice call +91 xxxxx xxxxx - null - null - null - null - null - null
    >> vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.video.call > xxxxxxxxxxxx@s.whatsapp.net - 0 -  Video call +91 xxxxx xxxxx - null - null - null - null - null - null
    >> vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2 > xxxxxxxxxx - 2 -  null - xxxxxxxxxxxxx - null - null - null - null - null
```

So, you see, they are saving the `DISPLAY_NAME` in the RawContact itslef, but how to update that name when it the name is updated from phone book ? Moreover, doesnt it make the aggregation feature completely useless ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't trust `Android` to merge your `RawContact`s into the desired Contact automatically, it isn't reliable, for example, if you have a married couple as two different contacts, each containing the same home phone number, Android should not merge those two.
   It'll only auto-aggregate if the similarity between two RawContacts crosses some threshold.

You should instead **explicitly** aggregate your new `RawContacts` with at least one (preferably **all**) existing `RawContacts` in that `Contact`, add to your ops an operation like this:

```
ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(AggregationExceptions.CONTENT_URI)
  .withValue(AggregationExceptions.TYPE, AggregationExceptions.TYPE_KEEP_TOGETHER)
  .withValue(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID1, yourNewRawContactId)
  .withValue(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID2, someExistingRawContactId)
  .build();
```

2. I don't think you need to add the display name to your `RawContact`, once you explicitly aggregate it into an existing `Contact`, it should inherit the primary display name set by some other `RawContact`

Comment: Explicit aggregation is known, but point is, is that how other apps like Signal and Whatsapp do ? if yes, why do they have added a display name in their RawContact ?

Comment: I think this is related to old Android devices, having issues with RawContacts without names, check on your target audience devices, and see if that works for you.

Comment: Also, the `87210` in that output the Contact's `_id` is a new Contact `_id` and not the one with which it should get aggregated .

Comment: in the case if its for the old versions, how would one update the `Display_name` if it gets changed ?

Comment: Btw, what is 'issues with RawContacts' can you point to some reference ?